# powershell ftp session download logs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I know there is a lot of stuff on ftp with powershell but i am strugerling to find the correct information. please can you guys help..

```
$today = (get-date).Date 
$dateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $today


$source = "ftp://username:password:servername"
$target = "\\Path\filename.zip"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile($source, $target)

"Downloading Log $File..."

$webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target)
```

I am trying to download the log files from a MSA P2000 controller, the commands would follow on a normal cmd session...

ftp "controllerName" username, password.. connection established. get logs filename.zip

how do i run the command get logs within the script to automate the process?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to do this via powershell and run it as a normal Batch file, dont know why i didnt do this in the first place!

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open serverName.domain.com
username
password
cd \\path for file
bin
hash
get logs test.zip
disconnect
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've found a solution, but if you're still itching for an answer... your `$source` variable may be wrong. You need to use the entire path, including the directory and file name relevant to the account's ftp site.

```
$source = "ftp://username:password:servername/path/to/file.log"
```

You can check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a code example since this is part of .NET.